# Teach in / teach on; class in / class on

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference between the usage of "in" or "on" in terms of class?

I'm teaching a class in/on math(s).
My father teaches a class in/on marine biology.

I have a class in French to go to tomorrow.
I have a class on historical artwork that I love.

I take a class in physics.
I'm not taking any classes on Spanish history this year.

The difference seems minimal, but it also seems to exist. For instance, "I'm not taking any classes *on* Spanish" sounds odd to me, as if to say you could take classes on Spanish as a whole language, and not as a student *of* the language, if that makes any sense.

Anyone have any idea what's going on with these two prepositions?

Comment: I think grammatically, both prepositions are acceptable and will work well. However, (a) the tendency to use *on* is catching on post-1950; (b) we can find many instances of mixed use by the same author in the same publication; (c) I myself use *in* for broader subjects ("in science") and *on* for specializations ("on advanced fluid dynamics") -- naturally?

Comment: Both sound somewhat awkward to me with maths and physics; I'd say _maths class_ and _physics class_. To me, _on_ implies that the class teaches knowledge _about_ or relating to the subject, but the subject itself is not what you learn. You learn _about_ Spanish history, but you don't learn the Spanish history; conversely, you do learn (the) Spanish (language) itself in a Spanish class, you don't just learn about it. The more the thing you learn is ‘metadata’ about the subject, rather than being the subject itself, the more likely I am to use _on_.

Comment: In the case of language classes, _in_ is ambiguous: _class in French_ could mean that the class teaches the French language or that it's a class on some other subject that is taught in French.

Comment: Note also that it's _math_ in American English, _maths_ in British English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chicago Manual of Style does not include the word "teach" in their list of common problematic words and the correct preposition construed with them.  It does include the verb "instill," and indicates that this verb is correctly used with the preposition "in."

More interesting, though, is the inclusion of the word "based."  It indicates that the following adjective should be "on" when used preceding a premise, and "in" when used preceding a field of study.

With this guideline, I would assume that the preposition used should be selected to convey either a summary of the class subject ("on"), or an immersion in the class subject ("in").  For instance, I would take a class in standard deviations if I was pursuing a degree in mathematics and had already acquired any prerequisite credits.  Or, I might take a class on carpet-laying at my local community college; the class subject is limited and does not imply a broader range of study.

It stands to reason that common use may default to prepositional accuracy without much conscious thought on the part of a speaker.  The preposition is likely considered further in written communication to convey credibility.

Comment: The reason that *teach* is not included in the problematic list, is that it is not problematic. You *teach* Spanish, you *teach* maths, you *teach* art history. The problem is *class in/on*.